# how to set a removeClass on all different section popouted in jquery?

Tags: jquery

i just don't undertstand how to remove all popout on my document.
I got materialize.js for whom who knows, and i used collapsible popout when users click on div collapsible-header. I've set a function when the on click is inside the section and another one when user clicks outside, in the document. But there is a bug : First of all when i open one section and let it open, then i open another, it doesn't close. But! when i click outside it works.

The problem is when i click again on a section there is bug... Any clue?
Here is my Html code:

```
        <div class="Tcard">
            <h4>Bloc 2</h4>
            <ul class="collapsible popout collapsible-accordion" data-collapsible="accordion">
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">subtitles</i>First</div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body">
                        <p>Ce paragraphe présente les prestations client sous forme de liste à puce</p>
                        <p><strong>Contribution</strong> H2</p>
                        <p>Phrases</p>
                        <p>Liste à puce + liens internes</p>
                        <p>CTA</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
                    <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

And for the Jquery's :

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if(!$(e.target).is('.collapsible-header, .collapsible-header *')){
        // alert ('ca va collapser');
        $('.popout>li').removeClass('active');
        $('.Tcard').removeClass('cpopout');
        $('.collapsible-body').stop(true, false).each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                $(this).slideUp({
                        duration: 350,
                        easing: "easeOutQuart",
                        queue: false,
                        complete: function () {
                            $(this).css('height', '');
                        }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        //alert('hey');
        //return traitement;
    }
});

$('.Tcard').each(function traitementPopout () {
    var $Tcard = $(this);
    $Tcard.on("click", function () {
        //alert ('je te popout le background');
        $Tcard.fadeIn('slow').addClass('cpopout');

        if ($('.collapsible-header').hasClass('active')) {
            $Tcard.fadeIn('slow').addClass('cpopout');
        }
        else {
            // alert('good bye le background');
            if ($('.Tcard').hasClass('cpopout')) {
                $Tcard.removeClass('cpopout');
            }
        }

    });
});
```

How to fix that : 1) each section close and only one stay open, 2) the outside click doesn't bug

Thanks for answers